# Is Encapsulation hiding unnecessary details from user or from another class?

Tags: android, oop, encapsulation

> One can visualize Encapsulation as the method of putting everything
> that is required to do the job, inside a capsule and presenting that
> capsule to the **user**. What it means is that by Encapsulation, all the
> necessary data and methods are bind together and all the unnecessary
> details are hidden to the normal **user**

> Encapsulation may also refer to a mechanism of restricting the direct access to some components of an object, such that **users** cannot access state values for all of the variables of a particular object.

Above two extracts i have taken from two different places.

Why they mention word **user** here?
I believe a user is someone who is using the product.Example. For an android app user is someone who is downloading and using the app..He/she only has access the the product functionality and not the code running behind it.So how is encapsulation hiding unnecessary details from user.Instead it's  hiding implementation details inside one class from another using private?

Comment: Another developer may be the user of your class, in which case you wouldn't want or need the developer to know how the class works internally.

Comment: To add to the comment above, sometimes the "other developer" you are helping with proper encapsulation is yourself 6 months in the future when you may have forgotten some of the nuances of the class you created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Users" here means other programmers who are going to use your code/API/library.

This is not an uncommon or unusual choice of words. If you want to refer to the users who are downloading and using the app, people usually use the term "end user".